# How to detect/read NFC tag in service

Tags: java, android, nfc

How can I read NFC tag in background via service? I already can read it in activity(I've found some source codes but I don't really understand how it works) but I can't find anything about reading it in Service or Runnable.

Thanks for help

Comment: AFAIK, NFC only triggers activities.

Comment: @CommonsWare That's correct. The reason is that they want the user to be aware of NFC tag interaction, for security.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for answer.
So here comes another question - how can I work with these triggers to run my code that works with NFC Card?

Comment: Put that code in an activity. The details depend a fair bit on the nature of the NFC tag and what is on it.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok... But how can I start that activity automatically(like NFC Taginfo app) when I put card to the reader(Nexus 7)?

Comment: That's a question of having the right `<intent-filter>` on the `<activity>` in the manifest. Again, it depends a lot on what sorts of tags you are trying to use.

Comment: If you cannot find what you need in the NFC documentation (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html), perhaps post a new StackOverflow question explaining what is on the tag (e.g., NDEF-formatted record with such-and-so data), and perhaps the community can help you craft the proper `<intent-filter>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i figured out how to solve it. I have to use these intent filters in AndroidManifest.xml to properly run my activity.

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
    <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```